# Finding R data frame values between two points in a separate reference data frame

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes in R:

df1:

| Category | Min | Max | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 3 | A |
| First | 4 | 6 | B |
| First | 7 | 9 | C |
| Second | 100 | 300 | D |
| Second | 400 | 600 | E |
| Second | 700 | 900 | F |

DF2:

| Name | First | Second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 5 | 200 |
| Beta | 8 | 500 |

I am trying to compare column values in DF2 for each category to their respective min/max in DF1 to create a new dataframe with values replaced by their ID from df1 (see below):

Desired Output:

| Name | First | Second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | B | D |
| Beta | C | E |

I have been experimenting with different functions but since the dataframes are structured differently with one being a data table and one being a reference table I'm thinking I may need a combination of functions and nested loops however I'm hoping there is an easier way.  Sincerely appreciate any thoughts and assistance.

Comment: So values can't be exactly min or max values, just strictly in between?

Comment: Not sure I follow but yes I believe the answer is values in df2 will be between the min and max in df1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% pivot_longer(-Name) %>% left_join(df1, join_by(name==Category)) %>% 
  filter(between(value,Min,Max)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(Name, names_from = name, values_from = ID)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Name  First Second
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 Alpha B     D     
2 Beta  C     E
```

Comment: I think I follow.  I should have mentioned there are other columns like address that are not important to this exercise but I think the code is trying to act on them.  Is there a way to ignore or select only specific matching columns?  Thanks!

Comment: could you please update the expected result, so as to understand

Comment: I made a subset data frame without the extra columns and the above worked perfectly.